# Truffle delpoyment Error: unknown account

Tags: contract-development, truffle, geth-debugging, truffle-deployment

i am trying to deploy my smart contract on live network, i have successfully deployed the same contract on rinkeby but facing error
while on live network, here is the detail

1 - Account balance

> 0.10000 ethers

2 - geth command

```
geth --rpc --rpcapi db,eth,net,web3,personal --unlock="0x1C11f6b1A2d1c0b00ad4145eb067184736EB973f"
```

3 - truffle js

```
"live": {
network_id: 1,
host: "127.0.0.1",
port: 8545, // Different than the default below
from: "0x1C11f6b1A2d1c0b00ad4145eb067184736EB973f",
gas: 4612388
}
```

4 - Error

```
truffle migrate --network liveUsing network 'live'.

Running migration: 1_initial_migration.js
Deploying Migrations...
... undefined
Error encountered, bailing. Network state unknown. Review successful transactions manually.
Error: unknown account
at Object.InvalidResponse (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:43303:16)
at /usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:331156:36
at /usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:175492:11
at /usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:314196:9
at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:315621:13)
at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:70159:18)
at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:70449:12)
at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:70604:12)
at IncomingMessage. (/usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:70564:24)
at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
```

OS: Linux
Node: 6.2
npm: 3.10